# Use jQuery to Output JSON from PHP Page

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a PHP page that outputs some JSON. After the page loads, I would like to output the JSON using jQuery AJAX. However, nothing is happening. The alert() dialog isn't appearing and it doesn't work with the JavaScript console, either. What is wrong with my jQuery AJAX call?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.ajax({ url: 'http://www.domain.com/page.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(obj.json_array[0]);
        alert(obj.json_array[1]);
        alert(obj.json_array[2]);
    }
});
</script>
```

The PHP is:

```
<?php
$array = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'bar' => 'foo',
    'int' => 4
];

$json_array = json_encode($array);
echo $json_array;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you can have arrays where each element has a key and a value, but once you parse it in javascript, that becomes an object. So using `[0]`, `[1]`, or `[2]` is invalid. You must use `foo`, `bar`, or `int`. Also, when you echo a string, the name of the variable that holds the string is not saved in any way. The only thing saved (echoed) is, well, the string. In your example, `echo $json_array;` echoes `{"foo":"bar","bar":"foo","int":4}`, and when it is parsed, you get an object. So you don't need to say `obj.json_array`, you just say `obj`. So to fix your issue,

Replace

```
alert(obj.json_array[0]);
alert(obj.json_array[1]);
alert(obj.json_array[2]);
```

with

```
alert(obj.foo);
alert(obj.bar);
alert(obj.int);
```

Comment: Hi Howzieky, I changed it to alert(obj.foo); but still, nothing is happening. No alert and it doesn't work in the JavaScript console either.

Comment: Can you put in `console.log(obj)` right after you set `obj`? What does it say?

Comment: I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined

Comment: You are certain this is after `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`? Try saying `console.log(data)` instead.

Comment: Yes, not sure what is wrong in my jQuery or AJAX call.

Comment: What did `console.log(data)` print out?

Comment: It printed out Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123657/discussion-between-howzieky-and-gts-joe).

Comment: Your suggestion in the chat about making sure my PHP script only outputs JSON (not HTML, JS or anything else) was what solved my problem. Thank you for going out of your way to help.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the update! Good luck with your project!